# How to avoid a:hover to act on img in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have the following selector:

```
a       { padding: 1em; }
a:hover { backgrond-color: #FF0000; }
```

And suppose I have the following HTML code:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com"><img src="so.jpg"></a>
```

What happens is that `<img>` gets red-background color on mouse hover.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks, Boda Cydo!

Comment: why not just remove the a:hover css?

Comment: because it's needed for text links

Answer (score 1):

Either be more specific about your `a:hover` selector

```
.something a:hover { background-color: #ff000; }
```

Or create another selector that blocks the background from being changed in the instances that you don't want it to

```
a.no-bg-change:hover { background: none !important; }

<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" class="no-bg-change"><img src="so.jpg"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your image is opaque, most of the time just removing the border and padding is enough to hide the red from showing.

```
a img { border: none; padding: 0; margin: -1em; }
```

A negative margin there to negates the `a` padding

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious how you're seeing the red background through a jpg. Nevertheless, this should do the trick.

```
a:hover img { 
  background:transparent; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('a').hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).has('img').css('background', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you won't believe me, but I had the same problem above and I resolved as follows:

I had something like this:

`<a href="#">`
        `<img src"path/to/image.gif">`
`</a>`

And in my CSS I had:

`a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }`

And, believe me, I just had to put the 'img' tag in the same line as the 'a' tag, like this:

`<a href="#"><img src="path/to/img.gif"></a>`

And that was all!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, you are saying to make `a` with background, but only if there is image, then do not. And what if a link has and a text and an image? Make it simpler, just tell exactly that you want. I assume you could do this for example:

```
<a href="..."><img src="so.jpg"></a>
<a href="..."><span class="text">some text</span></a>
<a href="..."><span class="text">some text</span> and <img src="so.jpg"></a>

a .text { padding: 1em; }
a:hover .text {background-color:#ff0}
```